# Applications that require privilege escalation don't ask for password and don't run

Tags: linux, linux-mint, gparted, privileges

I recently upgrade my machine from Linux Mint 17.3 to Mint 18.1 (by completely formatting and installing from clean).  I got pretty much back to a good state - with one exception.

When I had 17.3, if I execute (as a normal user) an application that requires elevated privileges (e.g. gparted, mint-update, etc.), I would normally get a prompt for privilege escalation.  Once I entered my password, the app would then run.

With the 18.1, I now don't get these prompts.  In fact, nothing happens at all.  Mint-update simply sits there for a few seconds, then shows an error message saying that update failed.  Gparted doesn't start at all.

If I start any of these applications from a terminal with sudo, then everything works correctly.

How can I get the old behaviour of prompting for privilege escalation back?

Comment: Did you perhaps forget to make your user a sudo user?  It sounds in your previous configuration your user was a sudo user set to prompt for the password (instead of configured for sudo without a password).

Comment: The user is configured correctly, as using sudo from command line works as expected, prompting for password. Yet UI apps don't prompt and don't do the actions.

Comment: Provide us the contents of your sudoer file please